# Error logging Spark model with MLflow on Databricks - mlflow.spark.log_model()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, apache-spark-ml, mlflow

I am attempting to log a Spark model using the code snippet below. The model metrics and parameters are saved in the ML flow run, but the model itself does not get saved under artefacts. However, when logging a Scikit-learn model using model.sklearn.log_model() in the same environment, the model gets successfully saved.

Environment:
Databricks 10.4 LTS ML cluster

```
train, test = train_test_random_split(conf, data)

experiment_name = "/mlflow_experiments/debug_spark_model"
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name)


evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()

rf = RandomForestClassifier()

param_grid = (
    ParamGridBuilder()
    .addGrid(rf.numTrees,[15)
    .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [6])
    .addGrid(
        rf.minInstancesPerNode,
       [7],
    )
    .build()
)

cv = CrossValidator(
    estimator=rf,
    estimatorParamMaps=param_grid,
    evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(metricName="areaUnderROC"),
    numFolds=10,
)
cv_model = cv.fit(train)

# best model
model = cv_model.bestModel

model_params_best = {
    "numTrees": cv_model.getEstimatorParamMaps()[np.argmax(cv_model.avgMetrics)][
        cv_model.bestModel.numTrees
    ],
    "maxDepth": cv_model.getEstimatorParamMaps()[np.argmax(cv_model.avgMetrics)][
        cv_model.bestModel.maxDepth
    ],
    "minInstancesPerNode": cv_model.getEstimatorParamMaps()[
        np.argmax(cv_model.avgMetrics)
    ][cv_model.bestModel.minInstancesPerNode],
}

model_metrics_best, artifacts_best, predicted_df_best = train_model(
    model, train, test, evaluator
)
with mlflow.start_run(run_name="debug_run_1"):
    run_id = mlflow.active_run().info.run_id
    mlflow.log_params(model_params_best)
    mlflow.log_metrics(model_metrics_best)

    #debug 1
    artifact_path = "best_model"
    mlflow.spark.log_model(spark_model = model, artifact_path = artifact_path) 
    source = get_artifact_uri(run_id=run_id, artifact_path=artifact_path)
```

It gives the below error.

> com.databricks.mlflowdbfs.MlflowHttpException: statusCode=404
> reasonPhrase=[Not Found]
> bodyMessage=[{"error_code":"RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Run
> 'bfe90fd5074f49c39a475b613d020cbf' not found."}]

[image]

I appreciate any direction for debugging or a solution regarding this error.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for this error or most of errors related to mlflowdbfs.

Disabling use of `mlflowdbfs` in Databricks ML Runtime cluster worked for above error. Another option will be using a normal Databricks Runtime cluster.

```
import os
os.environ["DISABLE_MLFLOWDBFS"] = "true"
```